# Intent filter for NFC Smart Poster

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I would like to create an application that catch all NFC Smart Poster record.
How can I catch Smart Poster records?
I tried this way:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

   <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
   <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
   <data android:mimeType="example/*" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
   <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
   <data android:mimeType="model/*" />
   <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
   <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
   <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

and this way:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:scheme="http"
         android:host="example.com"
         android:pathPrefix="/file" />
</intent-filter>
```

None of them worked with Smart Poster only plain text.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The URL filter should work fine as long as your smart poster record contains that URL. What does your Sp-record look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart Poster types and it's intent filters:

URL:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPrefix="" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Email:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Phone number

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

SMS

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="sms"/>
            <data android:scheme="smsto"/>
        </intent-filter>
```